# Question about design of css with yui drop down menu

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to incorporate this yui drop down menu control in a web page:
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/menu/

I have it working for the most part but I discovered that one of the css files that I need to link to as part of the control mess up the formatting for the rest of my web page. This is the css file in question:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?2.8.2r1/build/reset-fonts-grids/reset-fonts-grids.css">
```

and this is the guilty line:

```
body{text-align:center;}
```

I'm not that experienced with css, but this doesn't seem like the friendliest design. This property is being assigned to the entire body section of the html file and could (or does in my case) impact content separate from the yahoo stuff. I know that I can fix this by putting a div tag around my stuff and setting the text-align property back to what I want it to be, but I don't feel this should be necessary. Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need to add a div around your body. Just redefine body style in your CSS file like

`body{text-align:left;}` and make sure your CSS file comes after yahoo's css file.

You can also do it inline like

```
<body style="text-align:left;">
```

This will override yahoo's body declaration for `text-align`.